# How do i do non-nullish assertions for a generic function as an argument?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am writing a utility function that abstracts the ternary operator that returns an undefined by default if the condition argument is falsey.

```
export const ternary = <TReturn, TDefault = undefined>(
    condition: unknown,
    returnValue: TReturn,
    defaultValue?: TDefault,
) => {
    if (!condition) return defaultValue;
    return returnValue;
};
```

As the return value would be non-nullish due to the non-falsey check, how do i do a non-nullish type assertion on the return value within the ternary() function.

```
findAllUsers = (
        ctx: TRPCContext<"authenticated">,
        input: PaginationSchema,
    ) => {
        return ctx.db.query.users.findMany({
            limit: input.limit,
            where: ternary(input.cursor, gt(users.id, input.cursor)),
        });
    };
```

Typescript is erroring about input.cursor unable to be read cause of input could be undefined.

```
findAllUsers = (
        ctx: TRPCContext<"authenticated">,
        input: PaginationSchema,
    ) => {
        return ctx.db.query.users.findMany({
            limit: input.limit,
            where: ternary(input.cursor, gt(users.id, input.cursor!)),
        });
    };
```

I can do a non-nullish type assertion on input.cursor but i was wondering if there is any typescript way to make the non-nullish type assertion automatic?

Comment: Please post *code* not *images of code*.

Comment: This isn't currently possible. Please see the linked q/a and [ms/TS#49395](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49395) for more info.